# How to access element from custom event using svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg.js

Using svg.js, how do you access element from custom event?

```
myCircle.on('someEvent', function(event) {
    var circleX = event.x(); // event.x is not a function
    circleX = event.target.x() // event.x is not a function
    circleX = event.target.x() // event.target.x is not a function
    circleX = this.x()         // this is undefined
});
```

Using *this.* in `click` event works, but cannot use *this.* in custome events...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the element from event, events property target could be used ...

```
...
let element = SVG.get(event.target.id);
...
```